How to Zoom Tauri using Shortcuts
How to press cmd/ctrl+= to zoom in and cmd/ctrl+- to zoom out in tauri?
This feature is not enabled by default.

No extra coding, just change some configs.
src-tauri/tauri.conf.json
{
  ...
  "app": {
    "windows": [
      {
        ...
        "zoomHotkeysEnabled": true
      }
    ],
  },
  ...
}


src-tauri/capabilities/default.json
{
  ...
  "permissions": [
    ...
    "core:webview:allow-set-webview-zoom"
  ]
}


This is a pretty new feature and not yet well documented in the official docs. The VS Code plugin and config schema can be helpful.

